# Perforce and maven buildnumber plugin

Tags: maven, perforce, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I am trying to use the buildnumber-maven-plugin (v1.4) with a Perforce repository. I am getting the following logged messages:

```
[INFO] Got a revision during update: 4079887
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: null at timestamp: 1506951375881
```

The CreateMojo.update() method (line 524) is discovering the correct revision number (1st log message). However, after it is found an unconditional call to getRevision() (line 397) is made that wipes it out because it calls the *info()* method on the repository provider (which the perforce provider does not implement and simply returns null). I have also looked at the current source on GitHub (https://github.com/mojohaus/buildnumber-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/build/CreateMojo.java) and it appears that the issue is still there. Is there any plan to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What about offering a pull request to fix it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have submitted one.